# jQuery using slideDown and replaceWith together

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have two divs: div1 and div2

I am trying to achieve an effect where div1 animates to being transparent and at the end of it, div2 slides down on top of it (replacing div1).

Here is what I tried (http://jsfiddle.net/RHSgf/4/):

```
div1.animate({
   opacity: 0.0
}, 2000, function () {
   $(this).replaceWith(div2.hide().slideDown(2000, 'linear', function () {}));
});
```

But at the end of div1's animation, div2 isn't sliding down so elegantly.

I don't know why sliding down is so jerky. Thanks for any help in finding out the right way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move `slideDown` out of `replaceWith` and it should work:

```
$(this).replaceWith(div2.hide());
div2.slideDown(2000, 'linear');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/RHSgf/5/

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But can someone also please explain why this works as compared to my faulty code?

Comment: I don't know TBH, I just know it can't be done the other way because of what you just experienced.

Answer (score 3):

Try this and adjust timing as per your requirement !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () 

                      {
                        $("#div2").fadeOut(2000);
                        setTimeout(function () {  $("#div1").slideDown(2000); }, 2000);
                      }
                 );

</script>
```